# Lyx subsection shortcuts disabled

Tags: lyx, windows, keyboard

I am using Lyx 2.1.4 on a Windows System. When i need to create a subsection/pragrah i used the standard shortcuts Alt+A 1-5.

For some reason the shortcuts are now disabled (which lyx tells me down in the statusbar) and restarting lyx (as stated in other posts) did not work.

I did not change anything in my preferences lately except adding the hunspell directory.

How can i enable them again?

Comment: Are you by chance remembering the shortcut incorrectly? It should be Alt+P 1-5

Comment: @scottkosty you were kind of right. ALT+P worked. But i was 100% sure i used ALT+A before, so i played with the options. I changed the Interface language to English (from German), since i am writing an English Text, and somehow this changed the shortcut to ALT+P. Thank you.

Comment: Strange. I'm not sure what happened then. The shortcuts should not depend on the language (except for the Qt accelerator shortcuts). I'm glad that Alt+P works. Hopefully it is not too annoying for you to switch from Alt+A to Alt+P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default shortcut (independent of language) is <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> <kbd>1-5</kbd>.

However, it is possible to change the shortcut or add an additional shortcut that maps to the same functionality so that is probably why <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> worked for you before. Also, it's possible that <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> was different in LyX 2.0.x. In LyX 2.1.x (and also in the forthcoming LyX 2.2.x) <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> is used for inserting arguments.

Note that to define your own shortcuts, go to Tools > Preferences > Editing > Shortcuts. I'm actually not sure if it's currently possible to define multi-sequence shortcuts like the ones above.

Note also that your custom shortcuts are saved in the user.bind file. On Ubuntu, this file is located at ~/.lyx/bind/user.bind.